# .net MVC displaying multiple photos from db shows duplicate photo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, photo

I've used the examples I've seem on several forums to display an byte[] on a view. The problem I'm having is that sometimes a photo is duplicated on the view. For example I want to show photo1 and photo2. When the page loads I see photo1 and photo2. I refresh the page and I may see photo1 twice or photo2 twice.

Update:

I found my problem. I found a class that was not written to be thread safe deep in our backend code. It was holding state about the requested photo. So depending on the timing of the request for the photos two requests could return the same photo.

Here is my controller code.

```
    public virtual ActionResult GetImage(int id) {

        ClientDataPortal portal = new ClientDataPortal();
        GetPhotosCommand command = new GetPhotosCommand();
        command.GetPhotosActionEnum = GetPhotosActionEnum.GETDISTRIBUTORPHOTO;
        command.PhotoSearchCriteria = new PhotoSearchCriteria();
        command.PhotoSearchCriteria.DistributorPhotoId = id;
        DistributorPhotoData item = portal.Fetch<DistributorPhotoData>(command);
        //return new FileStreamResult(new System.IO.MemoryStream(item.Thumbnail), "image/jpeg");
        return File(item.Thumbnail, "image/jpeg");

    }
```

Here is the code in the view

```
            <table>
                @foreach (var item in Model.DistributorPhotos) {     
                    <tr>  
                        <td  id="item.DistributorPhotoId.ToString()" >              
                        <img id="item.DistributorPhotoId.ToString()" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Photo", new { id = item.DistributorPhotoId })" alt="Image" />
                        </td>
                        <td>@item.DistributorPhotoId.ToString()</td>
                   </tr>
                }
            </table>
```

Comment: What's the generated HTML?  Maybe the IDs in `Model.DistributorPhotos` has duplicates?